# Api gateway endpoint for both guest and authenticated users at the same time

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Is there any way to have an API Gateway endpoint to have a Cognito Authorizer and at the same time allow unauthenticated users.

The endpoint would be accessible to anyone, but if the user is authenticated I will grab his `id` and some other stuff.

At the moment my Cloudformation template looks something like this. I have already Cognito setup.

```
Resources:
  webApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          CognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !Ref UserPoolArn
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'*'"
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      StageName: !Ref Environment
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: "2.0"
        info:
          title:
            Ref: AWS::StackName
        paths:
          /authendpoint:
            post:
              security:
                - NONE: []
              responses: {}
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                ...
                httpMethod: "POST"
                type: "aws_proxy"

          /endpoint
            get:
              security:
                - NONE: []
              responses: {}
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                ...
                httpMethod: "POST"
                type: "aws_proxy"

  #FUNCTIONS ==========================================

...
```

I was thinking at building a custom authorizer, but I was wondering if there is a way to get it working without adding custom code

Thanks

EDIT: to clarify, all I need is an endpoint that given a token will retrieve the user info and attach it to the lambda request object, in the case of go it would be something like this `cognitoClaims := request.RequestContext.Authorizer["claims"]`. If the token is not passed in the header API Gateway will still allow guest users.

Comment: You cannot have a single API endpoint that supports and DOES NOT support authentication. Split your API into multiple resources - a /home resource where every user can reach and enter their credentials to redirect to /home/user_1.

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not clear enough. All I need is an endpoint that given a token will retrieve the user info and attach it to the lambda request object, in the case of go it would be something like this `cognitoClaims := request.RequestContext.Authorizer["claims"]`. If the token is not passed in the header API Gateway will still allow the user. 
I will as well edit my question.